# python: (pandas) how to obtain input argument value (but not the value itself)?

Tags: python, pandas

So let's say I have dataframes `tab1` and `tab2`.

I want to do something to the two tables, so I created a function and used these two tables as input.

Here's how my function looks:

```
def my_fxn(input1, input2):
    print('... combining '+input1+' to '+input2)
    # [DO SMTH TO THE TABLES]
```

When I call the function using my two tables:

```
my_fxn(tab1, tab2)
```

and my expected output from the print statement inside the function is:

```
"...combining tab1 to tab2"
```

So basically, I'm trying to retrieve the *names* of the original input I put in, and NOT the values.

Above print statement does not work because `input1` and `input2` are dataframes, so I cannot just concatenate them like that.

I also tried:

```
def my_fxn(input1, input2):
    print('... combining '+str(input1)+' to '+str(input2))
    # [DO SMTH TO THE TABLES]
```

But ofc this is also incorrect, as it's trying to convert the entire tables to string.

I've tried multiple ways of asking my question on Google, but I have not found another post regarding this.

Comment: like to each row ?

Comment: hi @joel.wilson no not to each row. my input was "tab1" and "tab2" so i want to print out my input, not to each row. oh let me make my question more clear in the question body. :) hope this made my question more clear!

Comment: why is this necessary? what use do you have with the name of a variable as a string?

Comment: @PaulH hi paul. I am trying to make it print so that when i run this function, i know which file is doing to which file, since the intputs to the function are both tables. just for my personal preference.

Comment: from experience, you're going down a deep rabbit hole for very marginal benefits.

Comment: @PaulH there's nothing wrong with curiosity to learn something right? :P

Comment: you should modify your function to accept the names of the files, then read the files to dataframes and operate on them. That way you can just print the filenames and not have to worry about what the variable is called.

Comment: yup!!! just thought of that and tried it after reading your previous comment. glad that you confirmed my approach to be an acceptable one! thank you!